# Curl - Downloading a file from Git

Tags: curl, download

I need to download an excel file using curl. I can only use http  and not ftp.
I tried few options but it every time returns the html with the links.

What is the option in curl i need to use?

Comment: "html with the links" - what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to find where on the server the Excel file is hosted, not the HTML page that downloads the file for you. Look in the HTML to see if you can find the link to the Excel file on the server and you can use this in curl.

Or, if you are lucky and things are configured correctly, you might be able to use the `-L` flag:

```
curl -L http://example.com/my.xlsx
```

I'll remove the git tag, as the question doesn't seem to relate to that.